# How to make application remember desktops for multiple windows on quitting and restarting

Tags: mac, osx-lion

In Mac OS X Lion when you quit an application with multiple windows on multiple desktops, it doesn't seem to remember which desktops they were assigned to on restarting?

Is there a setting to make this happen? or a hack, tweak or whatever?

Comment: There's a [similar question at Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44117/preserve-window-spaces-placement-between-restarts), but it doesn't mention any actual solutions at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a bug/missing feature depending on how you look at it..I'll leave the question here as well although 'ask different' seems to be meant for Apple

Comment: It looks like this is being addressed in Mavericks...sorta: http://youtu.be/Mi6AhogZCeg

Comment: Makes you feel nice when apple makes what should be a bug into a new OS version and then tries to make money from it..its a bug in functionality because apple supports multi monitors, desktops as well as reopening the windows on startup...missing out on remembering the desktops? BUG!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what your want, but there's a great application that I use on the Mac, called [Stay](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stay/id435410196?mt=12). It keeps track of where you put your applications when working with which monitors and ensures that the applications are put on the same displays when you restart, wake up from sleep or just plug in another monitor.